# unload event not firing in IE for window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

The idea is that window.open() saves and downloads a file and I have to update the table that contains the saved files using ajax.
I have the following code that works on Chrome and Firefox, but the "unload" event does not fire on IE.

```
        $(document).on('click', "#Download", function () {
            ...
            var popup = window.open("myurl", '_blank');

            $(popup).on("unload", function () {
                //Never gets here
                refreshTableWithSavedFiles();
            });
        });
```

Any ideas of how to make something like this works on IE will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work on newer versions of IE. If it is an older version that you are trying to target, you could try using `onunload` instead of `unload`